# Great circles and arcs of latitude

Tags: inequality

This inequality

cos(θ cos(α)) ≤ cos(θ) cos²(α) + sin²(α)

will prove that a great circle arc is shorter than an arc of constant latitude.

Prove the inequality.

Comment: I can't prove it.

Comment: We know that: have you tried taking the inverse cosine of both sides? You should also mention that $-2 \pi ≤ \theta ≤ 2 \pi$ for the inequality to be valid.

Comment: Give me a counterexample if θ ∉ [ -2π, 2π ].